# How do I export typeclasses?

Tags: haskell, module, typeclass

I am creating a file, `Common.hs`, which exports functions I commonly use. It also replaces some of Prelude's functions with versions I prefer:

```
-- Common.hs
module Common 
import qualified Prelude as Prelude
import qualified Data.Foldable as Foldable

sum      = Foldable.sum  -- I want to replace Prelude's sum
print    = Prelude.print -- I want to export Prelude's print
type Int = Prelude.Int   -- I want to export Prelude's Int
... etc (huge list) ...
```

This way, whenever I create a new Haskell file, I just have to import `Common` and compile it with `-XNoImplicitPrelude`:

```
-- Test.hs
import Common
main = print (sum [1,2,3]) -- will be the `sum` version I want
```

This approach seems to work, but I couldn't figure how to export typeclasses:

```
-- Test.hs
import Common
import Prelude (Show)

data Foo = Foo Int Int deriving Show

main = print (Foo 1 2)
```

Notice I had to manually import Prelude's Show. Is it possible to make `Common.hs` export it?

Comment: I think in this case you'll want to use an explicit export section on your `module` definition: https://www.haskell.org/onlinereport/modules.html

Comment: You may be interested in [classy-prelude](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/classy-prelude) which does many of these things. Also, starting with 7.10 many of the prelude functions are now re-exports of Foldable/Traversable instead of the list-specialized versions.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You have to explicitly re-export type classes (meaning you'll also have to explicitly export everything else), i.e.

Your Prelude:

```
module CustomPrelude (
  sum,
  product,
  Prelude.IO,
  Prelude.String,
  Prelude.print,
  Prelude.Show,
  Prelude.show,
  (Prelude.$),
  Prelude.Int,
  (++)
  )
where

import qualified Prelude
import Data.Foldable
import Data.Monoid

(++) :: Monoid m => m -> m -> m
(++) = mappend
```

Usage:

```
{-# LANGUAGE NoImplicitPrelude #-}
module PreludeTest where

import CustomPrelude

data A x = A x x

instance Show x => Show (A x) where
    show (A x y) = "A " ++ show x ++ " " ++ show y

main :: IO ()
main = print $ A (1::Int) 2
```

---

To save yourself some typing (and to keep your sanity while editing), you'd probably want to do:
A) Split your new prelude into several specialized files
B) Do module exports so you don't have to explicitly repeat everything

E.g.:

```
module CustomPrelude.Classes (Show,show,Functor,fmap, Monoid,mempty,mappend, Monad,return,(>>=))
where

import Data.Monoid
```

---

```
module CustomPrelude.Functions (
  module ReExport,
  Prelude.print,
  Prelude.IO, -- ok these technically aren't functions, but I didn't want to make yet another module just for demonstration purposes
  Prelude.String,
  Prelude.Int,
  (Prelude.$),
  (++)
)
where

import qualified Prelude
import Data.Foldable as ReExport
import Data.Traversable as ReExport
import Data.Monoid as ReExport


(++) :: Monoid m => m -> m -> m
(++) = mappend
```

---

```
module CustomPrelude (
  module P
  )
where

import CustomPrelude.Classes as P
import CustomPrelude.Functions as P
```

Note that you can save yourself quite a bit of typing work by renaming your reexported modules all to the same name when importing them.

Comment: as you can export a complete `module` as well you could split your `Common` into two parts (one with your methods where you export everything and then one *wrapped* around this that will export your desired classes and the complete *inner* module as well

Comment: That is a great idea @Carsten. Thank you both!

Comment: @Carsten I am currently writing an edit to that effect.

Comment: Note that `module Common (module Common) where ...` is perfectly valid, and means the same as `module Common where ...`. So it would be pretty easy to export everything + `Show` by writing `module Common (module Common, Show(..)) where ...`.